# Aligning widgets in a grid Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, alignment

I would like to centre align all my widgets inside a window created by Tkinter. All my widgets are using the grid geometry system. I have tried column and row weights but they do not work for rows and columns that I did not explicitly set. I also tried wrapping the entire window in a Frame and using grid(sticky=NSEW) but it does not make a difference. For my use case, I have more than 50 rows/columns and I would not want to run the weight setting on each of them.
This is what I have so far:

```
root = Tk()
root.minsize(500, 100)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.title('123')
root.iconbitmap(get_res_path('icon.ico'))

status_bar = LabelFrame(root, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
status_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=EW)
status_bar.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
status_bar.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
testing_text = Label(status_bar, text='', anchor=W)
testing_text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
status_text = Label(status_bar, text='Initializing', anchor=E)
status_text.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)

ver_msg = Label(root, text='123')
ver_msg.grid(row=0, column=0)
Frame(root).pack()
```

[image]

I would like every single element in the window (the text, entry box and button) to be in the middle of the window, and if I drag the window even larger, it is able to adjust itself to stay in the middle.

I have seen many questions but none has given me a working answer.

Comment: Maybe putting everything inside a frame and then use `pack()` on the frame might work

Comment: _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

Comment: Yea post some code so I can know what is going on here

Comment: 'root = Tk()
root.minsize(500, 100)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
Frame(root).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=NSEW)'

Comment: Edit it in the question, Billy

Comment: @CoolCloud I have updated it

Comment: What does the frame do...?

Comment: I copied this solution from another question. It is to wrap everything inside one object so that it can be treated as one object by the grid system and by using column and rows, I can center it. However it is not working fully due to the space at right side, although the question I copied this solution from marked it as working.

Comment: Use `.pack()` on it

Comment: Yea thats what I did, and it gave the error of cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack. I have included the complete code and python debugger is tellling me the error come from the .pack line.

Comment: Your supposed to put everything that is supposed to go inside the frame with frame as the container. If `frame = Frame(root)` then `button = Button(frame)` not `button = Button(root)`.

Comment: Oh thanks for the hint! I got it working as I wish. Would you like to transfer your comments into an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of here to center the entire app, is to place entire widget inside a frame and then use `pack()` on the main frame, like:

```
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

Button(frame, text='This is a button').grid(row=0,column=0)
Label(frame, text='This is a label').grid(row=1,column=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to align your widget to the left of the frame

```
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill=X, padx=5)
Button(frame, text='This is a button').grid(row=0,column=0)
Label(frame, text='This is a label').grid(row=1,column=0)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).